# Doxygen: Copy the description of a single parameter

Tags: parameters, doxygen

In my source code, I often got functions with the same parameter. Therefore the description for this parameter is also the same. I know I can copy documentations with \copybrief, \copydoc or \copydetails, but is their also an away to copy the description of a single parameter? Or is there a way to manage the description of this parameter at only on place in the code?

Thanks for you help
m0nKeY

Comment: Can noone help me to solve this problem? :-(

Comment: As far as I know there is no direct solution for this issue, there is no command like @copyparam. Did you have a look at the ALIAS command (in the Doxyfile) to define your own commands?

Comment: I know the ALIAS command, but is it then possible to mark a text-block and copy it?

Comment: As far as I know there is no functionality to grab a text block and use it in another command (except the \snippet command but that would make code out of it and I don't think that is the intention in a parameter description).

Answer (score 3):

So, it seems, that there is no solution for documenting the same parameter of different function at one point in code with doxygen.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I'm a bit late to the party. Haven't tried this out yet but I have noticed the commands [`\includedoc <file-name>`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdincludedoc) and
`\snippetdoc <file-name> ( block_id )`. They seem to allow you to put documentation into a separate file and then include it into you doxygen and have it "pasted" at the point of inclusion and parsed as doxygen. Thus, you could have a documentation "snippet" file and include the snippet you need to the common param. Might help...

EDIT: Tried this with 1.8.11 and it didn't work :( It appears this might be a 1.8.13 feature: [See this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45431868/doxygen-usage-of-includedoc).

Comment: \snippet and \include can copy only "code" (\code \endcode). AFAIK, it's not for params.