# Doxygen usage of \includedoc

Tags: doxygen

the [Doxygen documentation](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdincludedoc) says about **\includedoc**  *"This command works the same way as **\include**, but it will include the content of the file as if it were at the place where this command is called."*

So I set up `EXAMPLE_PATH = includepages` (Doxyfile) and created a file named `test.dox` in `includepages` sub folder.

To ensure that usages is correct this is the content of `test.dox`:

```
/*!
 *  THIS IS A TEST
 */
 THIS IS AN OTHER TEST
```

Here is the way I do Include this page:

```
 *  \include test.dox
 *
 *  \includedoc test.dox
```

This will result in:

[image: Screenshot Doxygen result]

As you see `\include test.dox` works like expected. The none doxygen part of the file `test.dox` is given (`THIS IS AN OTHER TEST`).
But instead of printing `THIS IS A TEST` `\includedoc test.dox` prints the file name?
I can't figure out whats wrong.

Thanks for helping
Tom

#### System information (SuSE Leap 42.2)

```
# uname -a
Linux twa 4.4.74-18.20-default #1 SMP Fri Jun 30 19:01:19 UTC 2017 (b5079b8) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
# doxygen --version
1.8.11
# dot -V
dot - graphviz version 2.38.0 (20140413.2041)
```

Comment: Please include the screenshot and not a link to the documentation. What is your setting for dox files (i.e. which language is used for a dox file, by default it is parsed by the C parser but this should not be a problem the problem might ly in the nesting of the comment in this case) what happens with the recent version 1.8.13 (you mention 1.8.11).

Comment: My screenshot can be displayed by clicking on "Screenshot Doxygen result"

I separated the problem in a project and did upload it to
http://www.nippyzip.com/uploads/170803073635-67250.zip
(Nippyzip just zipped my zip file so you have to unzip twice)

You will find a structure within this Project like that
 doxygen_incldoc
├── Doxyfile
├── include
│   └── my.h
└── includepages
    └── test.dox

The content of  is adapted for a better research
/*!
 *  THIS IS A DOXY COMMENT
 */
 THIS IS CONTENT

Comment: External links might vanish, please include the relevant parts in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I finally succeed in using the latest Doxygen version.

Here is a quick path to use Doxygen 1.8.13 on Linux:

```
wget http://ftp.stack.nl/pub/users/dimitri/doxygen-1.8.13.src.tar.gz
tar xvf doxygen-1.8.13.src.tar.gz 
cd doxygen-1.8.13/
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles"
make
sudo mkdir /opt/doxygen-1.8.13
cp bin/doxygen /opt/doxygen-1.8.13
```

Now you have the choice of using your distribution maintained version by calling **doxygen** or your own build version by calling **/opt/doxygen-1.8.13/doxygen**.

Comment: And what is the result?

Comment: \includedoc works like expected using doxygen-1.8.13. If some of the doxygen guyes does read this: Please expand your documentation by adding "Implemented since doxygen-1.8.13 [.12]?".